# Would a raspberry pi lifetime decrease if used 24/7?

Tags: pi-2, usb, corrupt

the topic technically says everything, I will be using Openmediavaults image on the raspberry pi. I will be using it as a home media server(Cause I have a spare Rpi2 doing nothing.)

People are saying that the SD card in raspberry pi has a limited life... Now, with Openmediavault, the SD card only holds the data of installs, and boot files and it's sort of like a new raspberry pi with raspbian but not too much data on it. 
I will be using a 8GB and 2*16GB thumb drives.

Can thumb drives easily be corrupted?

Comment: Different SD cards have different amount of care towards "wear leveling" which is trying to evenly use the entire space rather than pummeling one area with repeated writes which will eventually cause read/write failure in that area of the SD card. One thing that affects wear of the SD card is the page file being used and I have read of turning off paging with the Pi for some applications. Another consideration is environmental conditions and heat dissipation. Another consideration is power quality. Thumb drives can be corrupted though not easily under normal conditions.

Comment: @RichardChambers Paging doesn't increase wear on secondary storage, it decreases it because it is [about holding frequently accessed files in RAM instead of re-reading them from disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging).  There is however *swapping*, which happens when your RAM is used up and the kernel starts using secondary storage.  You can turn that off, in which case you will simply end up having processes killed by the kernel in order to free up memory.  Or you can reign in your memory use and set the system [swappiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness) to some low value.

Comment: WRT to SD cards, the topic has been done to death [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28844/5538) and elsewhere, it does not need to be revisited again.  In short, they wear out just like cars and underwear.  However, they are cheap to replace and should usually last for years of normal use (including as swap), and wasting your time trying to prolong that smacks of [lunacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder).

Comment: But the thing is, most of the data will becoming from the USB drives. The SD just runs the webpage, the media server and holds the installs. I know about wear levelling. I am not sure which SD card i will be using, as my father is bring one with him. Hopefully it will be a SanDisk :)