# Setting up "read-mostly" / "write-rarely" system - minimising writes as much as possible

Tags: filesystem, readwrite, logfiles

Per the title - I've seen all the stuff about using read-only filesystems and overlay filesystem but there's drawbacks with that - either you have to use multiple partitions, have some method of switching/remounting RW if you need to write some data, etc. and it clashes with our project's need to save some data on a fairly regular basis.

Being inclined to keep things easy and not mess too much with partitions and the like, I'm looking for guidance on how to stop or redirect all logging, temporary files, etc. to RAM and then *minimise* the amount of writing going on for anything that can't be stopped or redirected.

I know this is not "as good" as using the common methods but it (hopefully) avoids jumping through too many hoops / having to make too many checks/changes to normal conventions.

We need to write some relatively small amount of data semi-regularly, nothing that should trouble the lifespan of the average SD card or eMMC, but it would *vastly* improve matters if we can cut out or at least greatly reduce all the background writes that go on from default logging processes and the like.

Comment: You'll want to avoid reading this beyond the first paragraph: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28844/5538

Comment: How many of your SD Cards have worn out?

Comment: @Milliways it's a CM4 so eMMC, I'd just like to reduce the writing as much as possible for overall reliability & avoiding errors if the system is powered off unexpectedly. Many of these tweaks cost nothing so it's worth doing if you can.