# is it ok to link /var/log to /tmp or /run to save the SD card

Tags: sd-card, fstab, tmpfs

You have probably read the [Raspberry Pi: Extending the life of the SD card](https://www.zdnet.com/article/raspberry-pi-extending-the-life-of-the-sd-card/) article on zdnet by now. It features this line:

```
tmpfs    /var/log    tmpfs    defaults,noatime,nosuid,mode=0755,size=100m    0 0
```

However, I'd like to improve and just:

```
ln -s /tmp /var/log
```

Comment: Well, they both mean you will loose the files on shutdown -- so if you wanted to look through the logs after a system crash you will be out of luck.  Note that ZD net article was written 10 years ago and I'm inclined to believe the "SD lifespan problem" had more to do with the quality of the SD card reader on the earlier models (although I've never tried to research that in depth).   You might also want to consider the hype vs. the reality of this "problem": https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28842/reading-from-sd-card-all-day-long-risks/28844#28844

Comment: How many SD Cards have you had fail? I still use 12 year old cards; this is one of the Pi urban myths and you would be better to spend your time on something else.

Comment: I believe a great many users don't care about logs and RPi is meant to be a kind of toy anyway.

Answer (score 3):

A problem with this is that `/tmp` isn't a `tmpfs` mount by default on the current version of the OS (or on the last one or the one before that).  Have a look at `mount | grep tmp`.

Of course, you could link it to a directory in `/run` instead.  However, you'll have to arrange to have it created first, unless you just want to symlink it to `/run`, which seems messy, and if all this is about saving the effort it takes to add a line to `/etc/fstab`, silly as well.<sup>1</sup>

A more serious problem is that, particularly if the system runs without re-booting for a while and/or does stuff that creates copious logs, that tmpfs space isn't free -- it comes out of your RAM.  Tmpsf mounts are intended for temporary storage of small amount of rapidly and frequently accessed runtime data, which logs are not.

---

1. I won't repeat the paranoid-delusionally angle mentioned in my comment on your question, but don't forget about that either.

Comment: well, it's still `tmpfs` on my distro, hmmm, we need a compressed `tmpfs`

Comment: That maybe doesn't jibe w/ "rapidly and frequently accessed".   But: https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/blockdev/zram.html

Comment: I don't recall the specifics, but lz4 is so fast that it doesn't really matter, if you compress or not, or so I've read.